# Python-Selenium: Title is returning empty on website when using Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am having this weird issue where when I use

```
title = driver.title
print('Title is: ' + title)
```

the title returns blank or empty, it returns blank only on Firefox and with our internal website. When I use Chrome on our website it returns the actual title or if I use FF on a different websites they all return the title too. This test was running fine until a few weeks ago, Our Developers can't figure out what change might be causing this issue, Of course I can use Wait but our concern is what else might have broken.

Any Help is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Can you please add more detail to your question? As is, I'm voting to close this one, it is impossible for us to do remote debugging like that. We ain't wizards. (Obvious thing to do would be checking recent bug reports if you updated.) Which possible sources have you identified? Have you changed the website or just the Python script?

Comment: Done with the obvious things like checking bugs and other commits but not sure what went wrong,we have quite a few things that went in around that sprint and nothing looks like it broke something, we started writing automation scripts recently and during one of the demos the driver.title was working fine.
I am trying to see if anyone over here had similar experience and how they fixed it.

Comment: Please post a code example. Keep in mind that driver.title is async and might need to be awaited.